# C# - Low-Level-Key Hook and Handle the event

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C#.Net. I would like to use "Global-Low-Level-Key-Board-And-Mouse-Hook" library found at "https://github.com/rvknth043/Global-Low-Level-Key-Board-And-Mouse-Hook". Which is used to capture keyup and keydown event at low level.

Based on the documentation I can capture the key down and up event using the call back function as

```
 KeyboardHook keyboardHook = new KeyboardHook();
 keyboardHook.KeyDown += new KeyboardHook.KeyboardHookCallback(keyboardHook_KeyDown);
 keyboardHook.KeyUp += new KeyboardHook.KeyboardHookCallback(keyboardHook_KeyUp);
```

At inside `keyboardHook_KeyDown` && `keyboardHook_KeyUp` , I knew which key are up and down. However, I would like to handle this event to be true on some condition, for example if key "R" and "C" down then handle the event to true otherwise pass to application.

I went through the class and found `keyboardHook_KeyDown` && `keyboardHook_KeyUp` are defined as

```
public event KeyboardHookCallback KeyDown;
public event KeyboardHookCallback KeyUp;
```

Comment: what have you tried, what error are you getting, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to create your handlers with their own events inside and let the main application subscribe to that event, then when the handler receives an event it can process the ones it is interested in and pass the rest on to the application by issuing its own onEvent. If you require an example please post a comment and I will put something together.

Edit: May I ask why you want to use low level hooks, are the standard hooks inadequate for your purpose? You don't say what kind of application it is (forms, etc).

Comment: I want to prohibit combination key like CTL + TAB , CTL + ESC, ALT+ TAB

Comment: I see, you really want the windows level events, makes sense. My answer stands. Good luck.